# Websocket client not receiving response from node server using express

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I created a simple nodejs server with express to listen for a websocket connection, receive a "ping" string and return a "pong"  back to the client.

Everything seems to work fine except that the client is not receiving the "pong" from the server, even though the server supposedly sent it. Not sure if the problem is on the client or server side. I'm also running this on localhost, but that shouldn't be a problem right.

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var app = express();

var wsServer = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var host = wsServer.address().address;
  var port = wsServer.address().port;
  console.log('App listening at ws://%s:%s', host, port);
});

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: wsServer});
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('Got: %s', message);
    ws.send('Pong');
    console.log('Sent Pong');
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {

    console.log('Closed Connection');
  });
});

module.exports = server;
```

**Client**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebSocketTest() {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");
            ws.onopen = function() {
                var msg = {
                    msg: 'ping'
                };
                ws.send('Ping');
                console.log('Message sent to server');
            };

            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                console.log('Message received from server: ' + received_msg);
            };

            ws.onclose = function() {
                console.log('Connection closed');
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sse">
        <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code works on someone else's laptop, not on mine. I tried changing the IP, ports, added error logging. Still same results. The client doesn't get any response on the ws.onmessage even though the server is sending it something.

Comment: The code works but not on my company laptop. Must be an environment/firewall/antivirus issue. I tested it on cloud9 ide and it works fine.